# How to get a form submit button to save to localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a beginner and am trying to figure out how to get this to work.  I have a form and I want the submit button to be able to save to the localStorage.  So far, this is what I have.

```
<script>
function storeRecipe() {
    localStorage.setItem($("#recipe-name").val(), $("#recipe-
      description").val());
  console.log(Object.keys(localStorage));
}
</script>

<b>Recipe Name:</b>
<br>
<textarea id="recipe-name" rows="1" cols="35"></textarea>
<br><br>
<b>Recipe Description:</b>
<br>
<textarea id="recipe-description" rows="15" cols="35"></textarea>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send Recipe" onClick="storeRecipe()">
```

Comment: Your JavaScript needs to be in a `<script>`-block, for starters.

Comment: Sorry, it is in <script> tags.  I just didn't put them in here as I copied the code directly from jsfiddle.  When I click on the submit button, nothing happens.

Comment: Upon submit, you can stop the submission of the form and save each input field into a localStorage key. I'll update with an answer shortly.

Comment: Works exactly as expected for me: **https://jsfiddle.net/gLjedxnm/**. (I changed `localStorage` to `sessionStorage` as not to bloat my localStorage. And I changed `Object.keys(localStorage)` to `sessionStorage.getItem($("#recipe-name").val())` as to directly see the value, maybe that way your problem in the first place? You do know how to use *DevTools* in order to see the results of *console.log()*, right? *(F12 opens DevTools)*

Comment: Nothing happens for me when I hit the submit button.  Also, I see an error on the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon submit, you can stop the submission of the form and save each input field into as a localStorage key. Working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mr4ms4zp/. Open the console `cmd+opt+i` on macs to see the changed `localStorage` object.

```
<form method="POST">
  <b>Recipe Name:</b>
  <br>
  <textarea id="recipe-name" rows="1" cols="35"></textarea>
  <br><br>
  <b>Recipe Description:</b>
  <br>
  <textarea id="recipe-description" rows="15" cols="35"></textarea>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Send Recipe">
</form>

<script>
  document.querySelector('form').onsubmit = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = document.querySelector('#recipe-name').value;
    var description = document.querySelector('#recipe-description').value;
    localStorage["name"] = name;
    localStorage["description"] = description;
    console.log(localStorage);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: What is the error you get? It works perfectly in my local environment. I did make a couple of changes about 3 minutes ago, so maybe you're using old code?

Comment: When I clicked "Run code snippet" right below the code you provided, I got this:

Comment: {
  "message": "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 28,
  "colno": 5
}

Comment: When I ran it on jsfiddle, I got this:

{"error": "Please use POST request"}

Comment: It's a security feature of LocalStorage. So it will give the error on StackOverflow or any other site where you try to update the localStorage from a different origin. See [same origin policy] (https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwidhuLP1NfUAhUW9mMKHYobCigQFggqMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSame-origin_policy&usg=AFQjCNE6A0d-w9WfIkW8wsrfucTNFgW9Rw) . It should work just fine on your environment. Try it in your environment. Then `console.log(localStorage)` and you will see your variables.

Comment: I actually can't test it right now because the server I'm working on is down.  Should it work on jsfiddle?  What is the {"error": "Please use POST request"} message about?

Comment: You don't need to worry about that. If you do not explicitly set a form method browsers will default to using GET. I've updated the code. It doesn't really matter for you because you're not submitting the form to a server anyways.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mr4ms4zp/ works on jsFiddle. You can see the localStorage in the console. cmd+opt+i on mac.

Comment: Thank you for that.  If you don't mind, I have one more quick question.  What changes/additions do I have to make in order for this form to pop up when I click a button "Add a recipe"?  I know I have to create the button, but what do I do from there?  Something with onClick?

Comment: Also, is there a way to make it so the text in the text boxes disappear after submitting?

Comment: Many different ways. Add a button. Add an onclick event to the button. upon clicking, show the hidden form (so the form would have a `display:none` by default) and then upon clicking you would add a `display: block` or `display:flex` or whatever display you need. And yes. after updating the localStorage just do a `this.reset()` to reset the fields. You can choose to hide the form after too, so that it only appears again when the user clicks the button again. The possibilities are endless.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help.  I got it working now!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution with Vanilla Javascript**

```
function storeRecipe() {
    let name = document.getElementById("recipe-name").value;
    let description = document.getElementById("recipe-description").value
    localStorage.setItem(name, description);
}
```

Avoid the submit default behavior with event.preventDefault() or change the type of the button, i would recommend the second one:

```
<button type="button" value="Send Recipe" onClick"storeRecipe()">Submit</button>
```